# Java hangman project

Tags: java, arraylist

I have written code for a hangman game which loads the phrases for guessing from a text file. But when you enter a correct letter in the console it doesn't respond. 
What I am looking for is when you enter a correct letter it updates from 
this ************ to this ******a*****.
Below are two classes that I am using.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Application {

    private  ArrayList<Pirateword> piratewords;
    private Scanner input;
    Pirateword secretWord;
    private int attempts = 10;

    public Application(){

        input=new Scanner(System.in);
        piratewords=new ArrayList<Pirateword>();
    }

    public void runApplication() throws IOException {

        load("piratewords.txt");
        hangman();
        }

    public void load(String fileName) throws IOException{
        Scanner infile =new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
        int num=infile.nextInt();infile.nextLine();
        for (int i=0;i<num;i++) {
            String w=infile.nextLine();
            Pirateword p=new Pirateword(w);
            piratewords.add(p);
        }
        infile.close();
    }

    public  void hangman() {
        Collections.shuffle(piratewords);
        secretWord =  piratewords.get(0);

        int len = secretWord.length(); //Store the length which will be used to see if puzzle was solved.
        char[] temp = new char[len]; //Store a temp array which will be displayed to the user
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) //initialize the array
        {
            if(secretWord.charAt(i)!= ' '){
            temp[i] = '*';
            }
            else
            {
                temp[i] =' ';
            }
            }

        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("Word to date: ");
        while (attempts <= 10 && attempts > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nAttempts left: " + attempts);
            System.out.print("Enter letter: ");
            String test = input.next();

            if(test.length() != 1) 
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter 1 character");
                continue;
            }

            char testChar = test.charAt(0);

            //Find matches
            int foundPos = -2;
            int foundCount = 0; //How many matches did we find
            while((foundPos = secretWord.indexOf(testChar, foundPos + 1)) != -1)
            {
                temp[foundPos] = testChar; //Update the temp array from * to the correct character
                foundCount++;
                len--; //Decrease overall counter

            }

            if(foundCount == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, didn't find any matches for " + test);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Found " + foundCount + " matches for " + test);
            }

            //Print 
            for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(temp[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();

            if(len == 0)
            {
                break; //Solved!
            }

            attempts--;
        }

        if(len == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\n---------------------------");
            System.out.println("Solved!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("\n---------------------------");
            System.out.println("Sorry you didn't find the mystery word!");
            System.out.println("It was \"" + secretWord + "\"");

    }

}

}

import java.util.*;
public class Pirateword {
    private String word;


    public Pirateword(String w) {
        word=w;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return word;

    }

    public int length(){
        return word.length();
    }



    public char charAt(int i) {
    return word.charAt(i);
    }

    public int indexOf(char guess, int i) {
        return word.indexOf(guess);
    }

}
```

Comment: When the user guesses the right letter, add it to `temp` or another similar array like `progress` or `answer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this method `indexOf`, You don't use the second argument i.e starting index of search area.

```
public int indexOf(char guess, int i) {
    return word.indexOf(guess, i);
}
```

Also `foundPos` should initialize to -1.

Comment: Thank you. It now updates the correct letters but when I guess all the letters correctly within the attempts for some reason it doesn't say that you have won.

Comment: Can you give example of `word` and your `guesses` ?

Comment: `Attempts left: 5
Enter letter: t
Found 1 matches for t
ahoy the*e

Attempts left: 4
Enter letter: r
Found 1 matches for r
ahoy there

Attempts left: 3
Enter letter: `

Comment: `len` includes `space` also..So it does not become 0 yet..change `len` so as to remove number of spaces and include only characters

Comment: I tried `word.length() - word.replaceAll(" ","").length();` but it didn't work. I got the error  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Put `len =0`. Increment it inside this block.. `if(secretWord.charAt(i)!= ' '){ temp[i] = '*';len++;      }`

Comment: Ok done that but the error still comes up on the line `temp[foundPos] = testChar;` I think it's to do with foundPos